What's the standard method of downloading a file to a device over bluetooth?
I'm trying to develop a device which has a bluetooth module which can be connected to via an application, and have its files downloaded which are stored on an SD card on the device.
The idea is that the device will collect information, write said information to an SD card as a .csv file, and have the capability to have it downloaded to an external device (like a pc) over the bluetooth connection.
I'm still relatively new to bluetooth, so I am a little unsure on what the standard protocol is to achieve this. The steps to be followed are:
Device collects data and saves to SD card file system as .csv file
User connects to device over bluetooth using built application. The application can see what is on the SD card
User selects a file and presses "download"
File downloads to users device (eg pc)
Now, this file is already stored on the file system as a CSV file. When i want to download it, how do I do that? Do I stream the raw contents of the file over bluetooth to the end device? Or do I convert it to something like a binary and send that? Or is there something else I should focus on? My first assumption is that you would send a binary version of the file in byte chunks.
If you have any resources I should also read up on that would be greatly appreciated.

Is it Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) or Bluetooth Classic you will be working with? File transfer is often done with OBEX. There might also be useful information at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/. If you've not worked with Bluetooth before it might be worth taking a look at the GATT Specification Supplement on that page. Especially section 2.3.2 Scalar values to get a feel for how information is transmitted as binary values efficiently.

@ukBaz this is for BLE. Thanks I'll check it out. Got super overwhelmed when I opened the core specification document and saw it was 3000 pages.

As wrote above for Classic it is OBEX (OPP of FTP). For BLE there is also OBEX implementation but it requires some low-level protocols access what can be problem on some platforms. However, its not a problem to "re-implement" OBEX with common GATT communication.

For bluetooth ble, if you don't want to use gatt, you may use LE CREDIT BASED FLOW CONTROL MODE.

if you use btstack, there's a example
https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/le_credit_based_flow_control_mode_client.c
https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/le_credit_based_flow_control_mode_server.c

For someone new to Bluetooth the official documentation is pretty daunting and an initial workable solution would ideally be based on some straightforward LE characteristic set up for which understandable instructions exist. There are more sophisticated strategies involving notifications and larger MTU sizes, but this is an easily implementable method to start with.
Two characteristics on the server:

Control - 2 bytes writeable = Opcode, Index
                        Opcode = 0 set Data = data size
                        Opcode = 1 set Data = data slice Index


Data - 20 bytes readable


Suppose the server has 50 bytes to send. It waits for the client
to write Opcode,Index to Control. The client does the following:

Write to Control Opcode = 0
Delay for server to set Data = number of bytes to send = 50
Read Data = 50. Client knows it has to read 50 bytes.
Write Opcode = 1, Index = 0
Delay for server to set Data = first 20 bytes.
Read Data = first 20 bytes.
Write Opcode = 1, Index = 1
Delay for server to set Data = second 20 bytes.
Read Data = second 20 bytes.
Write Opcode = 1, Index = 2
Delay for server to set Data = final 10 bytes.
Read Data = final 10 bytes.

(However, a bi-directional serial Classic connection is better suited for file transfer and would be very much faster.)

For Bluetooth Classic, the Standard protocol for file transfer is OBEX FTP.
There is no standardised solution for Bluetooth LE, so you will have to come up with your own implementation.

There is Python code here that contains a fairly simple do-it-yourself (not standard) Bluetooth file transfer protocol using a Classic connection. The filetransfer.py file should run on any Python-capable machine such as a PC. It has an option to get a file
from a server. There is an initial exchange of information specifying the file name and size, and then a binary transfer process with a CRC check. Using the same principles it would be possible to add an exchange of available file names. On the other end, it depends on the identity of the Bluetooth module. Easiest option would be if it can also run filetransfer.py, otherwise the server code will have to be reproduced. If it is a Linux system such as a Raspberry Pi, then the other files on the site can be used - btferret.c and btferret.py have the same file transfer code that will act as a server for filetransfer.py.
https://github.com/petzval/btferret
